# Why does pip show tell me that I have numpy version 1.13.1, while Pandas thinks I have numpy version 1.8.0rc1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Why does pip show tell me that I have numpy version 1.13.1, while Pandas thinks I have numpy version 1.8.0rc1

I am getting the following error importing pandas. Can someone tell me how I can fix this.

1. Import pandas

   ```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from pandas.compat.numpy import *
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        'this pandas version'.format(_np_version))
    ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.9.0
    your numpy version is 1.8.0rc1.
    Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.9.0 to use this pandas version
   ```
2. These are the details of numpy on my machine

   ```
    pip show numpy 
    Name: numpy
    Version: 1.13.3
    Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
    Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
    Author: NumPy Developers
    Author-email: numpy-discussion@python.org
    License: BSD
    Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
   ```
3. These are the details of pandas on my machine

   ```
    Name: pandas
    Version: 0.21.1
    Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series,and statistics
    Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
    Author: The PyData Development Team
    Author-email: pydata@googlegroups.com
    License: BSD
    Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
    Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
   ```
4. I have tried uninstalling & reinstalling numpy

   ```
    sudo  pip uninstall numpy
    sudo  pip install numpy
   ```
5. I have checked pandas if there are any dependency issues

   ```
    pip check pandas         
    No broken requirements found.
   ```
6. I have tried unlinking and relinking numpy

   ```
    brew unlink numpy        
    brew link numpy

    Linking /usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.13.3... 
    Error: Could not symlink bin/f2py
    Target /usr/local/bin/f2py
    already exists. You may want to remove it:
      rm '/usr/local/bin/f2py'

    To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
      brew link --overwrite numpy

    To list all files that would be deleted:
      brew link --overwrite --dry-run numpy
   ```

Comment: What is your question? All that's posted so far is some error information.

Comment: it's not clear what your question is.  it look like you need to update or upgrade your numpy.  you may have path issues.

Comment: I think his question is "Why does `pip show` tell me that I have numpy version 1.13.1, while Pandas thinks I have numpy version 1.8.0rc1".

Comment: OP is Francesca.  not likely a 'his'

Comment: @ShpielMeister True enough.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon. I hope my question is clearer now! I am indeed a 'she'.

Comment: unfortunately the OP question is on hold.  you may have more than one version of python installed.  are you intentionally running python2.7 ? try which -a python

Comment: Hi @ShpielMeister I have Python 2.7.10.

Comment: How can I check if I have more than one python installed?

Comment: @FrancescaTabor  in the *nix terminal  enter `which -a python`.  if you are using brew that might be adding to the problem.   usually pip or conda is used to install numpy, sometimes it comes installed in your distro

Answer (score 0):

in python REPL (i'm using ipython)

```
In [98]: import numpy as np

In [99]: np.__version__
Out[99]: '1.13.3'

In [100]: np.__file__
Out[100]: '/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

this will show you where the numpy is coming from, and for pandas do this

```
In [103]: import pandas as pd

In [104]: pd.__version__
Out[104]: u'0.20.3'

In [105]: pd.__file__
Out[105]: '/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc'
```

in the terminal window enter `echo $PATH`